# Did I ground my ceiling fan correctly?

Tags: electrical, wiring, fans

[image]

Hello. I'm trying to wire a new ceiling fan. The instructions for the fan say to attach the ground wire from the fan mounting bracket + fan motor to the ground from the house (romex)

But, the instructions say nothing about attaching a ground to the actual box inside the ceiling. The fan box came with its own grounding nut.

So, I took the copper wire from the house/romex, fastened it to the ceiling box ground nut. Then, attached the remaining copper wire to the fan bracket + motor, so everything is touching.

Is this correct? Or am I doing something I shouldn't be doing?

All advice is deeply appreciated.

Comment: At my opinion this is useless because it is impossible to touch the box in the ceiling, and the box will be connected to the fan base by screws. It is unknown if the box can be connected to something inside ceiling also, depends of your house structure. I would advice to put flat and Grover washers on screws which hold fan base to the box, because holes are big, screw heads are small and fan is quite heavy and vibrating.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for pointing out why electrical codes are written by professionals and do not concern themselves with the opinion of the masses.

Comment: Yes. Electrical wiring should be done by person who knows electricity, wiring, building structure and local regulations. The last is important because of responsibility for consequences.

Answer (score 2):

The rule you're asking about is not specific to ceiling fans.

Metal electrical boxes need to be grounded so that if a hot wire touches the metal box then your circuit breaker will trip instead of leaving a live electrocution hazard for anyone who might touch the box.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  That makes sense. The instructions from the fan said that the ceiling box would be grounded from the screws holding the fan mount to the ceiling box. But the ceiling box has its own ground for a reason. So the way I have it is correct, despite the instructions saying otherwise?

Comment: @GuestRG Yes, your install appears to be correct and safe. I haven't seen any of the electrical veterans on this site chime in so I'd say you haven't done anything abhorrently dangerous =)

Comment: @GuestRG  Yes, what you did is correct. The instructions probably assumed the box was already grounded because you were just installing a fan. an existing box. +1

Comment: @JACK Side question: Can you have a short pig-tail from the box into a nut which also has the romex ground and fan ground? 3 wires in a nut.

Comment: @JACK How does it add a wire nut? You already needed one in order to ground the fan itself.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  My bad.... misunderstood your question. Yes, you can do that.